# java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed On InputStreamReader

Tags: java, jar, inputstream

I have the following problem:

When I load the resource from the project all works fine, but when I put it on a .jar and try to load I get an exception.

The code is:

```
InputStreamReader reader =
    new InputStreamReader(
        this.getClass().getResource(fileName).openStream())  
CsvReader stream = new CsvReader(reader);  
try {  
    while (stream.readRecord()) {  
        line = stream.getRawRecord();  
        //DO SOMETHING...  
    }  
}catch (Exception e) {  
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());  
    e.printStackTrace();  
} finally {  
    stream.close();  
}
```

And the stackTrace is:

```
    Inflater has been closed java.lang.NullPointerException: Inflater has been closed
 at java.util.zip.Inflater.ensureOpen(Inflater.java:364)
 at java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate(Inflater.java:237)
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:135)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:116)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:264)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:306)
 at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:158)
 at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:167)
 at utils.csvreader.CsvReader.checkDataLength(CsvReader.java:1198)
 at utils.csvreader.CsvReader.readRecord(CsvReader.java:604)
```

The problem happens on `stream.getRawRecord()`. I also tried with BufferedReader with same result on `readLine();`

Any ideas?

Comment: You're not closing the Reader.

Answer (score 1):

This can be bug in the Java. I had a similar problem, described here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-1032

Is your application running with some special class loader settings?

Comment: No, im using default settings but the problem looks the same that you had.

Comment: I cant fix it with the suggested workaround, i explicitly call the close() method but the problem occurs while still reading the file.

Answer (score -1):

loading resource from project means that you do not deal with zip (jar is zip), so InputStreamReader resolves to file you want to read.

My guess is that InputStreamReader resolves to null or wrong file when dealing with jar. Log vars to be asure

Comment: The file is inside de jar and sometimes works fine, i mean, the first time i try to read it fails but the second time it works ok (some times even the second time fails). But debugging i saw that InputStreamReader open the resource ok all the times (not null).

Comment: If the InputStreamReader was null it wouldn't appear in the stack trace.